# How to handle firebase database security rules on multiple updates?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I’m currently struggling to define database security rules.
During user profile creation I create an update object for the database in the form:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(firebaseUser => {
          const currentkey= firebaseUser.uid;
            var userCreateObject = {};
            userCreateObject['users/' + currentkey + '/username'] = username;
            userCreateObject['users/' + currentkey + '/email'] = email;
            userCreateObject['users/' + currentkey + '/birthdate'] = birthdate;
            userCreateObject['usernames/' + username] = currentkey;
            userCreateObject['followed/' + currentkey + '/MAINITEM/item'] = item;
            userCreateObject['filters/' + currentkey + '/MAINITEM/item'] = item;
            //Start account for the user
            firebase.database().ref().update(userCreateObject).then(function() {...})
...
});
```

However the following security rules cause the operation to fail:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "filters": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth.uid == $uid",
        ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
      }
    },
    "followed": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth.uid == $uid",
        ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
      }
    },
    "usernames": {
        ".read": "true",
        ".write": "auth.uid != null && (!data.exists())"
    },
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth.uid == $uid",
        ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Even when just testing the “users” part of the update, the permission is denied.
My cuestion is then, what is the proper way to define the rules so that they will accept the creation of the specified element even though it didn’t previously exist, an later on, accept modifications made by the user, again, in the form of an update?

Also, is there a specific way of testing this sort of rules? When defining them for the first time, I did simulations in the form:

/users/someuidImadeup

```
{
  "username": "username",
  "email": "email",
  "birthdate": "birthdate"
 }
```

Which worked properly. And

/users

```
{ "someuidImadeup":
 {
  "username": "username",
  "email": "email",
  "birthdate": "birthdate"
 }
}
```

That failed. So I assume updates are handled in this form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a wildcard under your rule for `/usernames`.

```
"usernames": {
    "$username": { /* this line/level is new */
      ".read": "true",
      ".write": "auth.uid != null && (!data.exists())"
    }
}
```

Without that additional level, the rule checks that there are no user names whatsoever, which is probably never true.

fyi: for additional security you might want to check that users can only write their own UID for the username with:

```
".write": "auth.uid != null && !data.exists() && newData.val() == auth.uid"
```

Comment: Thank you very much Frank. You seem to be absolutely right.
Regarding the security aspect, I’m getting into it, but I didn’t want to make the question more convoluted with additional rules, and luckily that aspect hasn’t given me too much trouble (yet…)